# Android - elements position indipendently from

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm new on the Android development and I have some problems to place views in a precise position, indipendently from the resolution or the screen size.

I have a background image and I would like to put TextViews/Buttons in a specific position without use dip coordinates.
I use a Frame Layout to put the background image and the views on different layers but the problem arise when I change screen resolution or screen size, the elements change position.

Do you know how I can solve this issue?

Thanks